# Java quartz scheduler is not working when set mysql lower_case_table_names attribute

Tags: java, mysql, quartz-scheduler

I am working with Java quartz scheduler and everything is working fine as expected.
Now I have made a change in the property of MySQL like lower_case_table_names=1(purposefully I need this setting).

But now I am getting table doesn't exist error when I try to query from quartz related tables;

Query from all other tables (named with the small letter and block letter)  are working without any issue.

See my query

```
select * from QRTZ_LOCKS;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'schema.qrtz_locks' doesn't exist
```